# Inheritance/Sub-Class Assistance

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to create a sub-class of my bank accounts with a checking and savings account sub-class. I have the accounts/sub-classes created, but I am having a hard time implementing the overdraw limit on the checking account and preventing the savings account from being overdrawn. I appreciate anyone who can help show me a way to manipulate these sub-classes more. Thank you!

Here is the code I have so far:

**Current Code**

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Accounts
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Account account = new Account(1122, 20000, .045);
    Account checkingAccount = new CheckingAccount (1500, 100.00, 0.6);
    java.util.Date dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    System.out.println("Checking Account ID: " + checkingAccount.id);
    System.out.println("Balance: $" + checkingAccount.balance);
    System.out.println("Balance after withdraw of $80: $" + checkingAccount.withdraw(80));
    //System.out.println("Overall Account ID: " + account.id);
    //System.out.println("Date Created: " + dateCreated);
    //System.out.println("Balance: $" + account.getBalance());
    //System.out.println("Interest Rate: " + account.getAnnualInterestRate() + "%");
    //System.out.println("Monthly Interest: $" + account.getMonthlyInterestRate()); 
    //System.out.println("Balance after withdraw of $2,500: $" + account.withdraw(2500));
    //System.out.println("Balance after deposit of $3,000: $" + account.deposit(3000));


}

//Create Account Class    
public static class Account
{
    //Define Variables
    public int id;
    public double balance; // Account Balance
    public double annualInterestRate;// Store Interest Rate
    private Date dateCreated; // Stores Account Creation Date

    // Account Constructor
    Account () 
    {
       id = 0;
       balance = 0.0;
       annualInterestRate = 0.0;                
    }

    // Account Constructor with id and initial balance
    Account(int newId, double newBalance) 
    {
    id = newId;
    balance = newBalance;
    }

    Account(int newId, double newBalance, double newAnnualInterestRate)
    {
    id = newId;
    balance = newBalance;
    annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
    }

    // Methods for id, balance, and annualInterestRate
    public int getId()
    {
    return id;
    }

    public double getBalance() 
    {
    return balance;
    }

    public double getAnnualInterestRate()
    {
    return annualInterestRate * 100;
    }

    public void setId(int newId)
    {
    id = newId;
    }

    public void setBalance(double newBalance)
    {
    balance = newBalance;
    }

    public void setAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate)
    {
    annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
    }

    // Accessor method for dateCreated
    public void setDateCreated(Date newDateCreated)
    {
    dateCreated = newDateCreated;
    }

    // Define method getMonthlyInterestRate
    double getMonthlyInterestRate()
    {
    return (annualInterestRate/12) * balance;
    }

    // Define method withdraw
    double withdraw(double amount) 
    {
    return balance -= amount;
    }

    // Define method deposit
    double deposit(double amount)
    {
    return balance += amount;   
    }

}

//Create Checking Account
public static class CheckingAccount extends Account
{        
    CheckingAccount (int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate) 
    {
        super(id, balance, annualInterestRate);
    }



}



//Create Savings Account
public class SavingsAccount extends Account
{
    //SavingsAccount constructor
    public SavingsAccount (int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate)
    {
        super(id, balance, annualInterestRate);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You may want to override `withdraw()` method in both sub-classes.

Comment: And you'd need an `if` clause to ensure that withdrawal is only allowed if `balance > amount`.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an example of override I can take a look like to see how override works? I have tried to go that route as well, but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: You could probably take a look at this 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm

Comment: That page only had an example of editing a class rather than the double I have setup for withdraw within my program.

Comment: Please see my edit to the Savings Account below.

Answer (score 0):

So I have edited the Savings Account to reflect not being able to withdraw if the account is less than zero, but it's not letting me use the statements.

**Savings Account Sub-Class**

```
    public class SavingsAccount extends Account
{
    //SavingsAccount constructor
    public SavingsAccount (int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate)
    {
        super(id, balance, annualInterestRate);

        public double withdraw(double amount)
        {
            if (balance < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Can't withdraw");
            }
            else (balance >= 0)
            {    
                    return balance -= amount;
            }    
        }
```